# Youtube get image url from channel (not getting image)

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to get the profile image of a youtube channel via direct url.

I found this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=brandingSettings&id={CHANNEL_ID}&key={GOOGLE_API_KEY}
```

But after after adding the channel id and my google api key I get this returned:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
 "etag": "\"0Fu6lI6VPydRdlQU3wwNfowdAUs/hirftF6Hp1SlcHf-VOY2asqIoJA\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 0,
  "resultsPerPage": 0
 },
 "items": []
}
```

I need a direct link to the image so I can add it to

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this url:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&forUsername={CHANNEL}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

It produces (Channel is FailArmy in this case):

```
{
  ...
  "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-_8lHSPO3nNI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/-THVRONaQco/s88-c-k-no-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-_8lHSPO3nNI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/-THVRONaQco/s240-c-k-no-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://yt3.ggpht.com/-_8lHSPO3nNI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/-THVRONaQco/s240-c-k-no-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg"
     }
    },
    ...
}
```

Update:

You can get the default url for example with: `response.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.default.url`